# Convert uint32 to const char* C++

Tags: c++, postgresql, uint32

I have a function that takes in `const char*` as argument, but the data I have is `Datum(PostgreSQL)`, which I am converting to `Uint32` using `DatumGetUint32() function`. I now need to convert it to `const char*` in `C++`. I have looked up online, many different websites but get no conclusive answer. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is because I have different functions that I have to pass the data to. Currently, the data is of form Uint32. The function however takes 'const char*' as the parameter. So my guess is to convert Uint32 to char and then pass it to the function using a pointer. But I am unsure how to proceed further. Hope this helps you to understand better!

Comment: How should it be converted? Please be more specific. Do you want the integral number as a string? E.g: `"10035"` for the value 10035?

Comment: So I have this Uint32 called keyval. I want to pass a const char*  pointing to it, in a function.

Comment: A const char* pointing to a Uint32? I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: This is because I have different functions that I have to pass the data to. Currently, the data is of form Uint32. The function however takes 'const char*' as the parameter. So my guess is to convert Uint32 to char and then pass it to the function using a pointer. But I am unsure how to proceed further. Hope this helps you to understand better!

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is

```
145 -> "145"
```

Then `sprintf` is a pretty standard way of doing the int to char* transition. Then you just have to cast the newly made `char*` as a `const char*` when you call your function.

Example:

```
char myString[10] = ""; // 4294967296 is the maximum for Uint32, so 10 characters it is
sprintf(myString, "%d", (long)myUint32); // where 'myUint32' is your Uint32 variable
my_function((const char*)myString); // where 'my_function' is your function requiring a const char*
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [boost lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html). I think it will help you.

Comment: +1 because Boost is pretty dandy for a lot of things, but most people don't have it and it can be a pain to install.